# Float left or right in layouts or containers?

Tags: apache-flex

[Flex 4] Float left or right in layouts or containers?
i have a main container, that is dynamic, 100% width, and in it there are 3 components. one should be floating to left, to right and the other will be centered. how do i do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What do you mean by float?  Is there any reason a group with a HorizontalLayout won't work?

```
<s:group layout="{new HorizontalLayout()}" width="100%>
 <container1>
 <container2>
 <container2>
</s:group>
```

Comment: float just like styles for html divs.
<s:group layout="{new HorizontalLayout()}" width="100%>
 <container1/>
 <container2/>
 <container3/>
</s:group>

the c1 must be floating to left
the c3 must be floating to right
and c2 must be in the middle

Comment: If memory serves me, doesn't the HTML Float allow for other "components" such as text to wrap around the floated component?  IF so, nothing like that exists in Flex.  You'd have to build it custom

Answer (score 1):

Add your 3 components to an HGroup (spark) or an HBox (halo).  If you want dividers that allow your components to be resized, you can use an HDividedBox.  Hope that helps.

Edit: Here's a code example based on your comment:

```
<s:HGroup width="100%">
    <s:Panel id="fixedPanel1" width="150"/>
    <s:Panel id="variablePanel" width="100%"/>
    <s:Panel id="fixedPanel2" width="150"/>
</s:HGroup>
```

Is this what your are looking for?

Comment: its like this horizontally:
|<-fix->|<-----var----->|<-fix->|
|<---------windows size-------->|
fix = fixed size component
var = variable size component